# Table joining using zend2 hydrate

Tags: orm, zend-framework2

I have a form to insert users to DB, which needs to update two tables @ once, **user** table and **user_role_linker** table. I am using hydrator (ClassMethod) to map my entities with the relative tables. I use two seperate entities, **User** and **UserRole**. The form contains all user fields that map with **User** table and user role field to map with **user_role_linker** table. When form submitted, bind the form with the User Entity.

```
    $user  = new \ZfcUser\Entity\User();
    $form  = $this->getRegisterForm();
    $form->setHydrator($this->getFormHydrator());
    $form->bind($user);

    $user = $form->getData();
```

Inserting is perform in two steps.

```
    $this->getUserMapper()->insert($user);
    $user_role_linker->setId($user->getId());
    $user_role_linker->setRoleId($data['user_role']);
    $this->getUserRoleLinkMapper()->insert($user_role_linker);
```

First insert the user and return the user_id,  then set user_id and user_role in **UserRole** entity and insert to table.

But now the problem is to fetch two table to one object or one array. I may need to perform a table join to get the solution. But there is no way I could find to join tables with using ClassMethod hydrator.

Please help me to accomplish this.

UserHydrator class

```
 namespace ZfcUser\Mapper;

 use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
 use ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface as UserEntityInterface;

 class UserHydrator extends ClassMethods
 {
/**
 * Extract values from an object
 *
 * @param  object $object
 * @return array
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function extract($object)
{
    if (!$object instanceof UserEntityInterface) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('$object must be an instance of ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface');
    }
    /* @var $object UserInterface*/
    $data = parent::extract($object);
    $data = $this->mapField('id', 'user_id', $data);
    //$data = $this->mapField('id', 'username', $data);
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Hydrate $object with the provided $data.
 *
 * @param  array $data
 * @param  object $object
 * @return UserInterface
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function hydrate(array $data, $object)
{
    if (!$object instanceof UserEntityInterface) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('$object must be an instance of ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface');
    }
    $data = $this->mapField('user_id', 'id', $data);
    return parent::hydrate($data, $object);
}

protected function mapField($keyFrom, $keyTo, array $array)
{
    $array[$keyTo] = $array[$keyFrom];
    unset($array[$keyFrom]);
    return $array;
}
}
```

Comment: A hydrator shouldn't do any joining etc, it's sole task is to convert from array to object and back, nothing more, nothing less :)

Comment: Actually, am changing the some one's module. In this case when I need to list down user details, I have to show the user role as well. Even though I join two tables when fetching the data, after hydration it only returns user table columns. :( @Andew

Comment: can you show some of the hydrator code? then I can help modify.

Comment: Edited the main post with the UserHydrator class code @Andrew